# This is strange question of Space Complexity. Can someone provide any insights?

Tags: c++, linked-list, space-complexity

I was solving this question when this approach clicked in -

Given a single linked list and an integer x. Your task is to complete the function deleteAllOccurances() which deletes all occurrences of a key x present in the linked list. The function takes two arguments: the head of the linked list and an integer x. The function should return the head of the modified linked list.

I am not sure what is the space complexity of my code.

I think since I am only using 1 extra Node space and simultaneously creating new nodes and deleting old ones, so it should be O(1).

```
Node* deleteAllOccurances(Node *head,int x)
{
   Node *new_head = new Node(-1);
   Node *tail = new_head;
   Node *temp = head;
   Node *q;

   while(temp != NULL) {
      if(temp->data != x) {
        tail->next = new Node(temp->data);
        tail = tail->next;
      }

       q = temp;
       delete q;
       temp = temp->next;
    }

   tail->next = NULL;
   return new_head->next;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you should be able to implement this function without ever calling the `new` operator at all.

Comment: As another side note, find the bug in this (wrong) part: `q = temp; delete q; temp = temp->next;`.

Comment: Also, memory leak of the node to which `new_head` points.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug @dxiv. I think I got it.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyFriesner, but i was trying a something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, kind of.

It depends on whether you are considering total allocations as a net change (in which case you're right).

**But** if you are thinking about the amount of times you hit the heap for new allocations, then it's using more space and a ton of computation. (A given C++ compiler and runtime is **not** obliged to guarantee immediately reusing space freed in the heap, just that it's *available* for reuse.)

As a C++ programmer for decades, what you're doing is mildly horrifying because you're doing a *lot* of new allocation. That results in thrashing the heap allocation structures.

Also, the way you're doing this is pushing stuff which doesn't match to the end of the list so you are shuffling the contents down.

Hint - you should not need to create **any** new Nodes.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I have found out the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since how much space you have allocated at any single time doesn't depend on the arguments (e.g. the length of the list or how many values of `x` are in the list) the space complexity of the function is `O(1)`

The practical point of space complexity is to see how much memory your algorithm will require. You never require more than 1 node of memory (plus the local variables) and `O(1)` reflects that.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring complexity in part depends on what you consider to be your variables. In terms of the number of nodes in the list, your algorithm is `O(1)` in space usage. However, this might not be the best perspective in this case.

Another variable in this situation is the size of a node. Often this aspect is ignored by complexity analysis, but I think it has value in this case. While your algorithm's space requirement does not depend on the number of nodes, it does depend on the size of a node. The more data in the node, the more space you need. Let `s` be the size of a single node; it would be fair to say that your algorithm's size requirement is `O(s)`.

The size requirement of the more common algorithm for this task is `O(1)` even when accounting for both the number of nodes and the size of each node. (It has no need to create any nodes, no need to copy data.) I would not recommend your algorithm over that one.

---

To avoid being all negative, I would view your approach as two independent changes to the traditional one. One change is the introduction of the dummy node `new_head`. This change is useful (and in fact is in use), even though your implementation leaks memory. It is only marginally less efficient than not using a dummy head, and it simplifies the logic for removing nodes from the front of the list. This is good as long as your node size is not overly large.

The other change is the switch to copying nodes instead of moving them. This is the cringe-worthy change as it gratuitously adds work to the programmer, the compiler, and the execution. Asymptotic analysis (big-O) might not pick up on this addition, but it is there with no beneficial gains. You've trashed a key benefit of linked lists and gotten nothing in return.

Let's look at dropping the second change. You would need to add one line, specifically initializing `new_head->next` to `head`, but this is balanced out by removing the need to set `tail->next` to `nullptr` at the end. Another addition is an `else` clause so that the lines currently run every iteration are not necessarily run every iteration. Beyond that are code removal and some name changes: drop the `temp` pointer (use `tail->next` instead) and drop the creation of new nodes in the loop. Taken together, these changes strictly reduce the work being done (and the memory needs) compared to your code.

To address the memory leak, I've used a local dummy node instead of dynamically allocating it. That removes the last use of `new`, which in turn removes most of the objections raised in the question's comments.

```
Node* deleteAllOccurances(Node *head, int x)
{
    Node new_head{-1};              //<-- Avoid dynamic allocation
    new_head.next = head;           //<-- added line
    Node *tail = &new_head;

    while(tail->next != nullptr) {
        if(tail->next->data != x) {
            tail = tail->next;
        }
        else {                      //<-- make the rest of the loop conditional
            Node *q = tail->next;
            tail->next = tail->next->next;
            delete q;
        }
    }

   return new_head.next;
}
```

This version removes the "cringe factor" as there is a benefit to the one node being created, and `new` is not being used. This version is clean enough to subject to complexity analysis without everyone asking "why???".

Comment: I was just trying a newer approach. As you said this algorithm is not at all recommendable over the general one.

Comment: @harsh_joeyit I've added an analysis of your changes. Perhaps you did not realize that one of your changes consisted of adding work for no benefit? That is the source of the negative reactions you've seen in comments. It's not so much about "something new" as about "something additional (with no gain)", a.k.a. "busywork", work for the sake of doing work. Trying new things is good, but keep in mind that a goal should be an improvement of some sort. Where is the special case when copying nodes has a benefit (even a minuscule benefit) over moving them?

Comment: Thanks. I'll remember that.